# Nuget package with GUI

Tags: c#, nuget-package

I tryin to write nuget package with some ability to user interaction (like entity framework for example) and write .tt templates to current project.

It is possibly to

1. Provide user select some source in rest or soap or some api via GUI?
2. Generate specific .tt template in current project based on user choise after first step?

Which way will enable to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can execute powershell script during installation. [More details are on the nuget site](https://docs.nuget.org/create/creating-and-publishing-a-package#automatically-running-powershell-scripts-during-package-installation-and-removal)

But! what about installation of the same package on the build server where the package might be needed to be installed in non-interactive fashion?